# Deserialise Json and Read Stream twice in C#

Tags: c#, http, stream

So this is a modern implementation of a HTTP client, trying to find a way to optimise/simplify this.
Specifically the DeserializeAsync method with the GetStream and the compiler statement for if/debug is a bit messy and I would love for a way to simplify it, but I don't want to remove the debug statement because I love to get the raw http response back in case the data models is changed by the back end team but it would be great if it was a bit simpler/clearer

```
// You should not dispose of HTTP client, so disable in this file.
#pragma warning disable CA2000 // Dispose objects before losing scope

namespace x
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     The request provider holds our Get/Put request to our APIs in generic format.
    ///     Implement this class in your services and use this to make requests to the API.
    /// </summary>
    public class RequestProvider : IRequestProvider
    {
        /// <summary> Json serialization rules </summary>
        private static JsonSerializerOptions _serializerOptions;

        /// <summary> Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RequestProvider" /> class. </summary>
        public RequestProvider()
        {
            _serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true, PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true, };
        }

        /// <summary> Returns the static method </summary>
        public Task DeleteAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken, string token = "")
        {
            return DeleteRequest(uri, cancellationToken, token);
        }

        /// <summary> Returns the static method </summary>
        public Task<TResult> GetAsync<TResult>(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken, string token = "")
        {
            return GetAsyncStream<TResult>(uri, cancellationToken, token);
        }

        /// <summary> The post async posts data to an API when logged in </summary>
        /// <param name="uri"> The uri we are posting to. </param>
        /// <param name="data"> The data we are posting. </param>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken"> Used to cancel the job </param>
        /// <param name="token"> The token identifying who we are. </param>
        /// <param name="header"> The header type we are using to post with HTTP client. </param>
        /// <typeparam name="TResult"> returns the generic results </typeparam>
        /// <returns> The result of the task is returned. <see cref="Task" />. </returns>
        public Task<TResult> PostAsync<TResult>(
            Uri uri,
            TResult data,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken,
            string token = "",
            string header = "")
        {
            return PostAsyncStream(uri, data, token, header, cancellationToken);
        }

        /// <summary> Send POST request to API from unauthenticated user </summary>
        /// <param name="uri"> The uri we are posting to. </param>
        /// <param name="data"> The data we are posting. </param>
        /// <param name="clientId"> The client id (who we are, i.e mobile). </param>
        /// <param name="clientSecret"> The client secret is an encryption to secure our token </param>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken"> Used to cancel the job </param>
        /// <typeparam name="TResult"> The result if it is success or failure </typeparam>
        /// <returns> The task is returned <see cref="Task" />. </returns>
        public async Task<TResult> PostAsync<TResult>(
            Uri uri,
            string data,
            string clientId,
            string clientSecret,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var httpClient = CreateHttpClient(string.Empty);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientId) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientSecret))
                AddBasicAuthenticationHeader(httpClient, clientId, clientSecret);

            var content = new StringContent(data);
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            var response =
                await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            content.Dispose();

            await HandleResponse(response).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var serialized = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            var result = await Task.Run(
                () => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TResult>(serialized, _serializerOptions),
                cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary> Send a DELETE request to the specified Uri as an asynchronous operation.</summary>
        /// <param name="uri"> The uri we are sending our delete request. </param>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken"> Used to cancel the job </param>
        /// <param name="token"> The token used by the API to authorize and identify. </param>
        /// <returns> The <see cref="Task" />. </returns>
        public static Task DeleteRequest(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken, string token = "")
        {
            var httpClient = CreateHttpClient(token);
            return httpClient.DeleteAsync(uri, cancellationToken);
        }

        /// <summary> Gets data from API in stream form authenticated users </summary>
        /// <param name="uri"> The uri we are sending our get request to. </param>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken"> Used to cancel the job </param>
        /// <param name="token"> The token identifying who we are. </param>
        /// <typeparam name="TResult"> Gets the generic results returned back </typeparam>
        /// <returns> The result of the task is returned <see cref="Task" />.</returns>
        public static async Task<TResult> GetAsyncStream<TResult>(
            Uri uri,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken,
            string token = "")
        {
            var request = CreateRequest(uri);

            var httpClient = CreateHttpClient(token);

            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(
                request,
                HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);

            await HandleResponse(response).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return await DeserializeAsync<TResult>(response, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        /// <summary> Enables us to connect to sites with localhost as certificate, enables GZIP decompression </summary>
        /// <returns> The <see cref="HttpClientHandler" />. </returns>
        public static HttpClientHandler GetHttpHandler()
        {
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip,
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) =>
                {
                    if (cert.Issuer.Equals("CN=localhost", StringComparison.Ordinal)) return true;

                    return errors == SslPolicyErrors.None;
                }
            };
            return handler;
        }

        /// <summary> Post a stream to the API </summary>
        /// <param name="uri"> The uri we are sending our get request to. </param>
        /// <param name="data"> The data we use to query the API (ex: userID) </param>
        /// <param name="token"> The token identifying who we are. </param>
        /// <param name="header"> The header type we are using to post with HTTP client. </param>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken"> Used to cancel the job </param>
        /// <typeparam name="TResult"> Generic param so we can return any object </typeparam>
        /// <returns> The <see cref="Task" />.  </returns>
        public static async Task<TResult> PostAsyncStream<TResult>(
            Uri uri,
            TResult data,
            string token,
            string header,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var httpClient = CreateHttpClient(token);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(header)) AddHeaderParameter(httpClient, header);

            var content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(data, _serializerOptions));
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            var response =
                await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);

            await HandleResponse(response).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return await DeserializeAsync<TResult>(response, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        /// <summary> The add basic authentication header. </summary>
        /// <param name="httpClient"> The http client in use </param>
        /// <param name="clientId"> The client id (who we are, i.e mobile). </param>
        /// <param name="clientSecret"> The client secret is an encryption to secure our token </param>
        private static void AddBasicAuthenticationHeader(HttpClient httpClient, string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            if (httpClient == null) return;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientId) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientSecret)) return;

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new BasicAuthenticationHeaderValue(clientId, clientSecret);
        }

        /// <summary> Adds the header to the http client </summary>
        /// <param name="httpClient"> The http client in use </param>
        /// <param name="parameter"> The parameter is what we put into the header </param>
        private static void AddHeaderParameter(HttpClient httpClient, string parameter)
        {
            if (httpClient == null) return;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter)) return;

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(parameter, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        }

        /// <summary> Creates an http client with token and automatically unzips Gzip files </summary>
        /// <param name="token"> The token default value is empty. </param>
        /// <returns> The <see cref="HttpClient" /> </returns>
        private static HttpClient CreateHttpClient(string token = "")
        {
            var handler = GetHttpHandler();
            var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token)) return httpClient;

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));

            return httpClient;
        }

        /// <summary> The create request. </summary>
        /// <param name="uri"> The uri. </param>
        /// <returns> The <see cref="HttpRequestMessage" />. </returns>
        private static HttpRequestMessage CreateRequest(Uri uri)
        {
            return new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
        }

        /// <summary> Deserialize Json streams </summary>
        /// <param name="response"> The message we got to deserialize </param>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken"> Cancellation settings depending on request </param>
        /// <typeparam name="TResult"> Generic parameter </typeparam>
        /// <returns> The <see cref="Task" />. we return the task </returns>
        private static async Task<TResult> DeserializeAsync<TResult>(
            HttpResponseMessage response,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await using var contentStream = await GetStream(response).ConfigureAwait(false);

#if DEBUG
            contentStream.Position = 0;
            var reader = new StreamReader(contentStream);
            var text = await reader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            contentStream.Position = 0;
            Debug.WriteLine("RECEIVED: " + text);
#endif

            return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<TResult>(
                contentStream,
                _serializerOptions,
                cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        private static async Task<Stream> GetStream(HttpResponseMessage response)
        {
            var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
#if DEBUG
            var target = new MemoryStream();
            await stream.CopyToAsync(target).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return target;
#endif
            return stream;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Handles the response via HTTP via checking if the Https call was valid.
        ///     If not throws exception.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="response"> The response. </param>
        /// <returns> The <see cref="Task" />. </returns>
        /// <exception cref="ServiceAuthenticationException"> Throws a service authentication error if not here. </exception>
        /// <exception cref="HttpRequestException"> Throws a general HttpRequestException unless forbidden or unauthorized. </exception>
        private static async Task HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
        {
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                throw new ServiceAuthenticationException(response.StatusCode, content);
            }
        }
    }
}

#pragma warning restore CA2000 // Dispose objects before losing scope
```

Comment: Hi @JsonDork! What are you looking for? An elegant alternative to `#if DEBUG` ? Or a smarter way to buffer response, like via `LoadIntoBufferAsync` ? Or something else?

Comment: No idea! I just feel that it's a big mess that part, it's important for me to write the HTTP response to assist in future debugging endevours but other than that I just feel it's a bit messy in some places an dwant to see if it can be still improved, can't think of any way personally.

Answer (score 1):

I was think a lot that should I write this answer or not. I don't want to be rude or offensive, but this piece of code is terribly. It has tremendous problems.

Let me just highlight a couple of them:

1. Initialization of the `JsonSerializationOptions`: You have a static variable, which you initialize in your instance level constructor always with the same values.
2. Exposing methods: Your `GetAsync`, `DeleteAsync`, `PostAsync` public functions are just calling the (also exposed) static counterparts (`GetAsyncStream`, `DeleteRequest`, `PostAsyncStream`). The naming inconsistency is just a bonus.
3. Create HttpClient: You should not create for each and every request a new HttpClient. There are hundreds of articles, which warns you. For instance [this](https://thecodebuzz.com/using-httpclient-best-practices-and-anti-patterns/)
4. Calling the Dispose manually: You should not call the `Dispose` manually (like: `content.Dispose()`)
5. Using `Task.Run` to deserialize result: I don't understand why do you do that? You also have a function called `DeserializeAsync`, which is used sometimes and sometimes not.
6. Lack of error handling: Checking just the `IsSuccessStatusCode` is really poor and naive. And translating every status code that is different than 2xx to `ServiceAuthenticationException` is ... well, it is not good.
7. etc...

Generally speaking it really hard to follow your code. The comments are pointless, variable names are just echoing their type, functional decomposition is done in the wrong way, like this:

```
private static HttpRequestMessage CreateRequest(Uri uri) 
  => new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
```

So, in summary I'm sorry but I have to say that not the `if DEBUG` is your biggest problem here.